# Mass infringement of Stack Exchange copyright

Tags: discussion, copyright

I recently asked [this same question on EL&U Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6966/mass-infringement-of-our-copyright?noredirect=1#comment26148_6966):

> The website [Learnhub.org](http://learnhub.org/) seems to be [copying content wholesale from EL&U](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=EL%26U+learnhub.rog&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=VmqSVZ20HcbyUL2qi6AI#q=EL%26U+learnhub.rog&filter=0) without any attribution at all. Unlike with [this blogsite problem](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2152/is-http-englishqna-blogspot-com-violating-elu-or-your-copyright/2154#2154), there isn't even a link back to the original EL&U posts. So apart from your material being published without respecting your moral right to be recognised as the author of your own work, EL&U content is not recognised as belonging to EL&U. The questions and answers there even appear in the same order that they appear in on EL&U if ordered by reputation.
>
> I don't really wish to scan through learnhub.org to find all my posts so that I can make an individual complaint for each one, and I don't suppose you guys would want to do that for yours either. Can EL&U help us get this content removed from that site, given that both questions and answers from here are appearing there together?

I was advised to bring the question here:

> "Though the content in question in specific to EL&U, the broader phenomenon of content scraping is observed across all of SE, and so this might be better discussed on Meta Stack Exchange. In particular, since the StackExchange corporation (not community) is the only one empowered (or at least likely) to bring legal action, and since C&D letters have a lot more pull coming from corporations rather than individuals, I think it would be best brought to their attention. They're active on on Meta.SE, but less often visit the local !etas"

I suspect that content from all over Stack Exchange is being abused in this way on Learnhub.org. Can the powers that be step in on our behalf (as well as SO's)?