# Can we see the spreadsheet of sites that are being monitored for republishing SE material without proper attribution?

Tags: feature-request

I recently (a few hours ago) posted this unpopular question here:

- [What's being done to protect users' copyright?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272500/whats-being-done-to-protect-users-copyright?noredirect=1#comment884828_272500)

Animuson gave a very helpful [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272500/whats-being-done-to-protect-users-copyright/272501#272501) in which he detailed a lot of useful information including the fact that there is now a spreadsheet of scraper sites which also details other information such as how urgently these sites need to be addressed.

Previously there was a messy page for reporting scraper sites, which it rapidly proved difficult to manage. For this reason there are new reporting procedures in place, which readers may be familiar with.

Animuson comments in his post:

> > As far as a publicly accessible list: we had considered making this new system public, but opted to keep it private since we don't want users messing around with the records or entering things on their own. Allowing this just creates more work for those who are processing these, which is exactly what we're trying to cut down on by making this new system in the first place. Keeping users out of these areas would require a login system, which we simply weren't interested in building for a tool like this. Hence, it was kept private and only accessible to Stack Exchange staff.

I understand the problems that would ensue if users were able to actually enter or amend things on this spreadsheet. But, now that there is no longer any publicly visible list of sites, would it be possible to publish this spreadsheet - or its most salient content - so that users could at least see it. This may help publicly reassure users about the fact that S.E. is addressing this issue and also enable them to see who exactly is reusing their content.

Comment: To clarify, the spreadsheet is being deprecated, and I don't believe it's even been updated in several months since we've entered all those more recent reports into our new system instead. The spreadsheet will go away completely once the data we need from it has been transferred to our new system. As far as dumping the database from the new system, that's something we *could* probably do, but it would likely end up being one of those things that never actually gets done because no one remembers to do it until someone notices the data is *x* months old now.