# List of malicious sites that proxy logins

Tags: discussion, feature-request

**Is there a publicly available list of known malicious clones of Stack Exchange sites that proxy logins?**

It would be a very useful feature to have a community-maintained list of all known proxy sites that pose a significant security vulnerability/phishing risk to any users.

As pointed out by [animuson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/141525/animuson) in the comments below, a similar [list has existed in the past](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272506/can-we-see-the-spreadsheet-of-sites-that-are-being-monitored-for-republishing-se).

---

Note:
I have just found a site which proxies your login and reported it as [discussed here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/a-site-or-scraper-is-copying-content-from-stack-exchange-what-do-i-do):

- http://7f4c919540be6ec81cd37d9e61da6c37.extratorrent.filespook.com/

Comment: Not a duplicate. It takes quite a while for reports to go through so for example an adblock list or some other tool that checks against the just reported sites would be a great improvement!

Comment: There is a list, but we don't publicize it simply because we have no reason to expend the effort to make it public. Maybe if I'm really bored one day it'll happen. Most of these sites end up blocked from our servers or go offline naturally shortly after being reported, so the information isn't super useful.

Comment: Why not outsource the task of keeping the list updated to the community? It takes far too long for the sites to disappear from any search engine. A browser plugin would take care of stopping anyone entering their credentials on a clone minutes after it is being reported!

Comment: Keeping the list updated isn't a particularly difficult task. We considered making the tool public, but allowing users to just insert and do whatever they want then requires us to moderate those actions to make sure they're not abusing it - we achieve nothing in the end.

Comment: Also related: [Can we see the spreadsheet of sites that are being monitored for republishing SE material without proper attribution?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272506/can-we-see-the-spreadsheet-of-sites-that-are-being-monitored-for-republishing-se)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no such list.

As Animuson points out in the comment below, there used to be one, but it wasn't helpful - it did not actually help to determine who to contact, or precisely what was being violated.

Personally, I think there could also be legal issues if such a list were published, but that was not what motivated Stack Overflows decision.

We will simply have to make sure we're on the right site, or that any site copying content from SO is providing attribution.

Comment: There's no legal repercussions that I know of, and legal aspects played no part in our decision not to make it public - we actually used to let users keep and maintain a list of these sites in a Meta answer long ago. We stopped because it was horribly disorganized and wasn't actually helping us determine who to contact, etc. It was just a long list of links with no information on what was being violated or how often users were hitting it.

Comment: @animuson Thanks - updated my answer.